# Does Selflocalizer get map via service call from MapServer?

Tags: ros, nav2d, nav2d-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not shown in rqt_graph the service call connection for SelfLocalizer node to where ?
From `rosnode info SelfLocalizer` it shows

```
* /SelfLocalizer/get_loggers
 * /SelfLocalizer/set_logger_level
```

Are they from MapServer node ? And what does MapServer node do, because is is not in Nav2d package ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237050/does-selflocalizer-get-map-via-service-call-from-mapserver-?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-06-15**:
afaik mapserver publishes the map as it is (occupancy grid). The localization happens with other algorithms, like AMCL for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is, but service connections are not shown in rqt_graph. You can use "rosservice list" to show the available services, but this will also not show which node is calling these services.

The MapServer is from the ros-navigation stack: http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-06-16**:
Thanks for confirming that.